# Chart.js only positive values in tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js and wanted to make a "age distribution" graphics for customers.
I used the horizontalBar so it looks like in the image (male and female).
For the dataset, to get the pyramide, I multiplied the female values with *-1 so get negative valus and then did the same with the xAxes tick callback if the label is negative.
Now, when I hover my house, the tooltip for the female is still negative. I found a way to multiply it all with *-1, but then the males are negative and the females are negative :-)

I'd appreciate some help how to do this with only one data.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs

Comment: Oh well... sometimes you do not remember the easiest things. Thanks :)